# Looking for books on the history of chemistry?

Tags: chemistry, resource-recommendation, book-recommendation

I'm looking for good books on history of chemistry and chemical methodology. There appear to be surprisingly few available on the market based on my own 'research' (just googling and phrase-searching for different variations on 'history','chemistry'). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree that there are (surprisingly?) few books on the history of chemistry.

The most succinct one is probably C. Cobb, H. Goldwhite; "Creations of Fire - Chemistry's Lively History from Alchemy to the Atomic Age"

Much more detailed, although somewhat old now, is A. Ladenburg; "Lectures on the History of the Development of Chemistry Since the Time of Lavoisier". Is a very good book, even if it is difficult to read since chemistry in the 19th century lacked a lot of our concepts, but I think the author does a good job in not only presenting the material as well as analyzing the thoughts of our predecessors.

In the real of comprehensiveness you cannot do better than J. R. Partington, "A History of Chemistry", in four massive volumes, covering a lot from the greeks until modern chemistry.

For a lighter reading I highly recommend S. Kean; "The Disappearing Spoon". Is not so much a history book, but rather a collection of anecdotes from the history of chemistry. Each chapter selects a couple of elements from the periodic table and then recounts some historical events relating to these elements. Is not an academic view, but it is very entertaining, and surprisingly illuminating.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend Norton's History of Chemistry by William Brock.

For a history of the periodic table try my own:

Eric Scerri, The Periodic Table, Its Story and Its Significance, OUP, 2007.

Answer (score 0):

I found an exhausting volume that spends too long on earlier efforts at explanations of nature. It may have the range you are looking for.  I believe the title is *The Chemical Philosophy*.